# Want to use filter criteria in query for opportunity

Tags: apex, soql

Error in saving unable to apply filter on opportunity

```
global class batchClassOppUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       String query='Select id   from OpportunityContactRole Where IsPrimary=true AND OpportunityId IN (SELECT Id from Opportunity where recordtype.name = 'XYZ Solutions')';
         
          return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OpportunityContactRole> Scope){
        for(OpportunityContactRole a:scope){
            a.isPrimary= true;
            
            
        }
        update scope;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       String query='Select id   from OpportunityContactRole Where IsPrimary=true AND OpportunityId IN (SELECT Id from Opportunity where recordtype.name = 'XYZ Solutions')';
```

You have to escape nested single quotes in Apex.

But here, you don't need Dynamic SOQL at all. Just use a static query:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id 
    FROM OpportunityContactRole 
    WHERE IsPrimary = true AND OpportunityId IN 
          (SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE RecordType.Name = 'XYZ Solutions')
]);
```

You also don't need the semi-join. You can traverse the relationship to Opportunity directly in your query:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id 
    FROM OpportunityContactRole 
    WHERE IsPrimary = true AND Opportunity.RecordType.Name = 'XYZ Solutions'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to escape the quote characters (e.g. `\'XYZ Solutions\'`). However, you should use an inline query instead:

```
  return Database.getQueryLocator([
      Select id   from OpportunityContactRole Where IsPrimary=true AND OpportunityId IN (SELECT Id from Opportunity where recordtype.name = 'XYZ Solutions')
  ]);
```